# Resizing images in a flex container

Tags: css, image, flexbox

Im trying to have 3 images side by side in a flex container but the images are much too large and its stretching the page and creating a scroll bar.Tried a tip to use flex wrap but that didn't work.Should I just resize in photoshop?[image].

```
<section class="main-content">
        
        <div class="image">
          <img src="img/devil-ivy-can.jpg">
        </div>
        
       <div class="image">
          <img src="img/krimson-princess-can.jpg">
       </div>

        <div class="image">
          <img src="img/spiderwort-can.jpg">
        </div>
        

      </section>
```

```
.main-content{
  display: flex;

}

div{
  width:100%;
  
  padding:10px;
  margin:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    .container {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        background-color: grey;
    }

    img {
        width: 100%;
    }

    div {
        flex: 1;
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 10px;
    }


  <section class="container">
        
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://atlas-content1-cdn.pixelsquid.com/assets_v2/127/1273408777629996108/jpeg-600/G13.jpg">
        </div>
        
       <div class="image">
          <img src="https://atlas-content1-cdn.pixelsquid.com/assets_v2/127/1273408777629996108/jpeg-600/G13.jpg">
       </div>

        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://atlas-content1-cdn.pixelsquid.com/assets_v2/127/1273408777629996108/jpeg-600/G13.jpg">
        </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: Ah I see what the issue was. Was using Image instead of img on the CSS. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

hello i have try to solve your problem you can try this in your CSS code.

```css
.main-content{
  display: flex;
  gap:10px
}
div{
  width:100%;
  gap:10px;

}div.image img{
  width:100%;
  object-fit:cover;
}
```

```html
<section class="main-content">
        
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://www.imgonline.com.ua/examples/random-pixels-wallpaper.jpg">
        </div>
        
       <div class="image">
          <img src="https://www.imgonline.com.ua/examples/random-pixels-wallpaper.jpg">
       </div>

        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://www.imgonline.com.ua/examples/random-pixels-wallpaper.jpg">
        </div>
        

      </section>
```

in your css code at div selector i prefer using gap to give space between items than using padding and a margin

if you give the img width 100% it will fill the div.image and set object-fit with value cover. The CSS object-fit property is used to specify how an  or  should be resized to fit its container.